# How to use phraseexpress to ALLCAPS a set of highlighted text?

Tags: windows-10, macros, phraseexpress

I want to highlight a given piece of text, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to immediately uppercase all of those characters back in

I read the macro manual and I still couldn't find a simple solution to this

For reference, this is what my settings look like

[image]

How exactly do you do this?

Comment: please don't use http link for images. Use stackexchange is switching to https and will edit your link anyway

Comment: i tried but it was confusing since i didn't have 10 reputation and had limited  image privliages

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out

```
{#clipboard -cut}{#uppercase {#insertclipboard}}
```

[image]

I didn't look closely, but when you select "CONVERT TO UPPERCASE" it gives you a list of preformatted suggestions here:

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly and you don't even have to copy any text. Just select and execute macro.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without obliterating what's on the clipboard? Why isn't there simply a way to get the selected text and then have the output of the macros replace the selected text? Instead, you have to bring it in via the clipboard, manipulate it, and then output it. A user of `Ctrl-Shift-U` sees the text transformed before their eyes, and they would never realize that the contents of the clipboard were toasted in the process.